# vsphere-connect lib of nodejs

Tags: node.js, vsphere

I am trying to use the same instance of a vsphere in many functions

Here is the lib [vsphere-connect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vsphere-connect)

```
const vSphereClient = vSphereConnect.createClient({
host: '',
username: '',
password: '',
ignoreSSL: true,
autoLogin: true,
exclusive: true,
})
```

Actually I got this.

```
exports.getVCenterInfo = function getVCenterInfo(req, res) {
!I would like to use an instance there!
}
```

I tried

> vSphereClient.retrieve({ some code here})

Into my function but it doesn't work.
Can someone help me please ?

Answer (score 1):

As i understand from the lib link you can't use it like this `const vSphereClient = vSphereConnect.createClient({` because in vSphereClient you will get pending promise.

Maybe you will write lib named vsphereLib like this:

```
const connect = require('vsphere-connect');

let clientInstance;

connect.createClient({
    host: 'vcenter.mydomain.com',
    username: 'administrator@vsphere.local',
    password: 'vmware1',
    ignoreSSL: true,
    autoLogin: true
})
    .then(function (client) {
        clientInstance = client;
    });

module.exports = {
    getClient: () => clientInstance,
};
```

Usage will be:

```
const client = require('./vsphereLib').getClient;
exports.getVCenterInfo = function getVCenterInfo(req, res) {
client()
    .retrieve({
        type: 'VirtualMachine',
        id: ['vm-1234', 'vm-5678'],
        properties: ['name', 'config.version']
    })
    .then(function (results) {
        console.log(results);
    })
    .caught(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

The only one problem is if connection will fail your code will fail aswell,so maybe you should extend vsphereLib with init function and run it before server starts

Comment: Hhm ok thanks, let me test that and tell you if it's ok :)